# Issue with jQuery chat form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chat

Thank you for the help in advance.

This project is a signup form that will use a chat system to collect the user's profile details during their onboarding process. This is my first jQuery project, so I am struggling to spot my mistakes.

My jQuery should append the value in the textarea to the *#message-feed* div and apply the CSS classes of *.message*, *.bubble* and *.user* to the new element it creates.

However, when I type into the text area and click submit, it flashes the value I have just typed with no styling in the message feed, but it instantly disappears.

The reason for this CSS structure is the interchangeability between the *.bot* and *.user* classes depending on whether it is a question presented to the user by the website, or a user's response to a question.

Here is a link for a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamievineup/f4avmvdt/) but it loads very differently than on my local machine (JSFiddle shows errors.

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="message-feed">
        <h1>Let&#39;s get to know you a little bit more&hellip;</h1>
    </div>

    <form method="POST">
        <div id="text-response">
        <textarea id="text-response" placeholder="Type in here&hellip;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="submit-response">
    </form>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
width: 320px;
height: 480px;
background-color: #fff;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-240px 0 0 -160px;
}

#message-feed {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message {
padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
width: 90%;
}

.message:after {
content:"";
display: block;
clear: both;
}

.bubble {
border: 0.5px solid #005393;
max-width: 80%;
padding: 10px;
}

.bot {
color: #005393;
float: left;
border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0px;
}

.user {
float: right;
background-color: #005393;
border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 12px;
color: #fff;
}

#text-response {
height: 23px;
width: 220px;
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
background-color: #fff;
float: left;
}

textarea {
height: 20px;
width: 220px;
float: left;
resize: none;
border: none;
padding: 10px;
line-height: 22px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 15px;
outline: none;
overflow: auto;
}

.submit-response {
height: 45px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #005393;
color: #fff;
float: right;
text-align: center;
line-height: 42px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 15px;
outline: none;
border: 0;
}

.submit-response:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.submit-response').click(function() {

        var $newMessage = $('textarea[name=text-response]').val()

        $('#message-feed').append($newMessage, 'message', 'bubble', 'user');

    });
});
```

Comment: You didn't say what problem you have. Is the problem located in HTML not changing as you want it to change, or is it that the page changes when you submit ? Or both ?

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe the problem.  What exactly are you asking us?

Comment: Sorry guys, just amended the post to include the issue

Answer (score 1):

2 problems over there :

1/ You're not preventing the event default behavior. That means whenever you're clicking on the button which is a submit input, it will send a POST request. So the page will change. To prevent this :

```
$('.submit-response').click(function() {
    var $newMessage = $('textarea[name=text-response]').val();
    $('#message-feed').append($newMessage, 'message', 'bubble', 'user');
});
```

should become :

```
$('.submit-response').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    var $newMessage = $('textarea[name=text-response]').val();
    $('#message-feed').append($newMessage, 'message', 'bubble', 'user');
});
```

2/ You're not actually adding the classes. `$.append` appends **elements**, not classes. So :

```
$('.submit-response').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    var $newMessage = $('textarea[name=text-response]').val()
    $('#message-feed').append($newMessage, 'message', 'bubble', 'user');
});
```

should become :

```
$('.submit-response').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    var $newMessageText = $('textarea[name=text-response]').val(),
        $newMessage = $('<span class="message bubble user">' + $newMessageText + '</span>');

    $('#message-feed').append($newMessage);
});
```

Now obviously it doesn't have to be a span, it could be anything else. It still has to be an element.

Also, this is only resolving the issues you had on the front end. You'll need AJAX to send the POST to the server side and get the data without refreshing/leaving the page. But that's another topic.

Comment: Steve, thank you very much for explanation and amendments, they were very helpful. The appendments are now showing up in the message feed, but they are saying 'undefined' rather than the actual text that is submitted. Do you have any ideas where I could be going wrong?